# Django ForeignKey returning id instead of name

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Api return:

```
{
    "id": "2c1f7627-ae73-4ca3-8243-82bc61e84dc7",
    "title": "fdgdfg",
    "author": "a8e13c21-f1ad-4292-9f73-dcb2e8757350",
    "price": "234234.00",
    "published": "2021-08-26",
    "edition": "dfgdfg",
    "isbn_code": "dfgdfg",
    "created_at": "2021-08-26T05:16:33.022617+02:00",
    "updated_at": "2021-08-26T05:16:33.023618+02:00",
    "pages": 342,
    "description": "sdfsdfsdf",
    "cover": "HARDCOVER",
    "genre": "ACTION",
    "language": "SERBIAN",
    "format": "A3",
    "publisher": "BIG_5"
}
```

Models:

```
class Book(models.Model):
id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
title = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
author = models.ForeignKey(Author, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=255)
published = models.DateField()
edition = models.CharField(max_length=255)
isbn_code = models.CharField(max_length=255)
pages = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True, default=0)
description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
cover = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Cover.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
genre = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Genre.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
language = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Language.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
format = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Format.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
publisher = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Publisher.choices(), default=None, null=True, blank=True)
created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title

class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'Book'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Books'
```

Serizalizers:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = Book
    fields = ('id', 'title', 'author',
              'price', 'published', 'edition',
              "isbn_code", 'created_at', "updated_at",
              "pages", "description", "cover",
              "genre", "language", "format",
              "publisher"
              )
```

And so i want to get the author name instead of id in the api.
Ask any questions you have, i really need help with this since ive been struggling with this for some time.

Im told to add more details in here but theres nothing else to say about this

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see this question named [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please [edit] the question and include code fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can work with a [**`SlugRelatedField`** <sup>[DRF-doc]</sup>](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) as `author`, and thus implement this as:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializers.SlugRelatedField(
        slug_field='full_name',
        queryset=Author.objects.all()
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Book
        # …
```

The advantage of using a `SlugRelatedField`, si that it can be used both in the read and write direction: if one specifies the `full_name` of an `Author`, then one can use the `BookSerializer` to create, update and retrieve the details of a `Book`.

Comment: assert self.queryset is not None or kwargs.get('read_only', None), (
AssertionError: Relational field must provide a `queryset` argument, override `get_queryset`, or set read_only=`True`. Thats the error im getting when i try to do that

Comment: @Aleksa: yes, you need to specify the `queryset=` as well. Made a typo.

Comment: queryset in serializer?

Comment: @Aleksa: in the `SlugRelatedField` serializer. This is useful to make the serializer work in both the *read* and *write* direction.

Comment: it`s work for me, but when try to create a user will show errors like "field error"

Comment: @Virus: in that case, you use `user = ...` instead of `author = ...` and with the `User` model, and with `slug_field` the field you want to use to specify the user (for example `'email'`). It also should be included in the `fields = ...` in the `Meta`.

Answer (score 3):

can do it like this:

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    author = serializer.ReadOnlyField(source='author.full_name')
        
    class Meta:
        model = Book
        fields = ('id', 'title', 'author',
                  'price', 'published', 'edition',
                  "isbn_code", 'created_at', "updated_at",
                  "pages", "description", "cover",
                  "genre", "language", "format",
                  "publisher"
        )
```

Comment: Thank you as well, ive got the answer :)